# Most occuring string in data using pandas - n gram data mining

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a data in following form present in a **single column** in csv file.

```
['hhcb', 'hcbc', 'cbcc', 'bccc', 'cccd', 'ccdd', 'cddh']
['fahb', 'ahba', 'hbac', 'bacc']
['hchc', 'chcb', 'hcbh']
['hhhh', 'hhhh', 'hhhc', 'hhcd', 'hcdc', 'cdcc']
['habb', 'abbb', 'bbbb', 'bbbc', 'bbcc', 'bccd', 'ccdh', 'cdhd']
```

I have to find the most occurring four length string in this data.
Please suggest the way.
(It is an example, the original data is large)

Comment: What do you mean by _single column_? What does, for example, the corresponding dataframe look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) `Series` for creating `DataFrame`, then [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html). Last one possible filter top values is by [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.head.html) or `[:5]`:

```
print df
                                                  a
0        [hhcb, hcbc, cbcc, bccc, cccd, ccdd, cddh]
1                          [fahb, ahba, hbac, bacc]
2                                [hchc, chcb, hcbh]
3              [hhhh, hhhh, hhhc, hhcd, hcdc, cdcc]
4  [habb, abbb, bbbb, bbbc, bbcc, bccd, ccdh, cdhd]

print df.a.apply(pd.Series).stack().value_counts()[:1]
hhhh    2
dtype: int64
```

EDIT:

If you need top `5` with remove duplicates in each row, use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html):

```
print df
                                                  a
0        [hhcb, hhcb, cbcc, bccc, bbbb, hhcb, hhcb]
1                          [fahb, ahba, hhcd, fahb]
2                                [hcbh, hhcd, hcbh]
3              [hhhh, hhhh, hhhc, hhcd, hhcb, bbbb]
4  [habb, habb, bbbb, bbbc, cbcc, bccd, ccdh, cdhd]

df1 = df.a.apply(pd.Series)
          .stack()
          .groupby(level=0)
          .apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates())
          .value_counts()[:5]

print df1
bbbb    3
hhcd    3
hhcb    2
cbcc    2
habb    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.
Suppose i want to calculate the most common string across rows, what changes do i need to do in the code.

Comment: No problem, I can change solution. Give me a time.

Comment: Is neccessary first filter data with length = 4? Or all data have length = 4? Do you need only top value, or top value and count of top value?

Comment: All data have fixed length. In this case it is 4. I also need count of few top values. Thanks

Comment: And you need only top string?

Comment: I need few (atleast 5) top strings.

Comment: Please check solution, for top `2` values, then you can change  it to `5`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109757/discussion-between-nishant-ranjan-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Counter`, updating it for each word that is of length four.  Then use `most_common()` to get the top values.

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
for row in df.ngram.values:
    for word in row:
        if len(word) == 4:
            c.update([word])

>>> c.most_common()[0]
('hhhh', 2)
```

**Timings**

```
%%timeit
for row in df.ngram.values:
    for word in row:
        if len(word) == 4:
            c.update([word])
10000 loops, best of 3: 87.7 µs per loop

%%timeit
df.ngram.apply(pd.Series).stack().value_counts().head(1)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.4 ms per loop

%timeit pd.Series(df.ngram.sum()).value_counts().index[0]
1000 loops, best of 3: 474 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way.

```
In [78]: ngram
Out[78]:
0          [hhcb, hcbc, cbcc, bccc, cccd, ccdd, cddh]
1                            [fahb, ahba, hbac, bacc]
2                                  [hchc, chcb, hcbh]
3                [hhhh, hhhh, hhhc, hhcd, hcdc, cdcc]
4    [habb, abbb, bbbb, bbbc, bbcc, bccd, ccdh, cdhd]
dtype: object

In [79]: pd.Series(ngram.sum()).value_counts()[:1]
Out[79]:
hhhh    2
dtype: int64
```

To kind of cheat with `.sum()` operation, which will join the lists.

Comment: ngram is dataframe having 1 column. It is giving me error
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: We need to use the name of column in sum. The code will  be
pd.Series(ngram.nameofcolumn.sum()).value_counts()[:1]

Comment: Then you need to call `ngram[colname]`. In this case ngram is series.